# why this code is not working?

Tags: jquery, html

I want to show values of two radio buttons in the span tag when they are clicked, but this is not working :

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
        <title>Untitled Document</title>
        <script src="jquery.js" type="text/javascript">
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>
            your amount is : <span id="displayPrice"></span>
        </p>
        <input type="radio" value="159" name="price" onclick="$('displayPrice').html(this.value)">
        <br>
        <input type="radio" value="259" name="price" onclick="$('displayPrice').html(this.value)">
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Gavin's answer is correct, but you'd benefit from supplying more information in your questions.  Simply saying that something doesn't work and posting your code isn't usually a recipe for success.

Comment: Yet, the info pasted was enough to find an answer..

Comment: Sure, in this case it wasn't all that tricky, but it sure wasn't obvious what the problem was until you looked at his code.  As a potential answerer of questions, would you prefer that someone make an effort to describe the problem, or would you prefer that they left it to you to discover what the problem even was?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

$('displayPrice') isn't a valid selector. You're wanting $('#displayPrice').

After the fact, but for what it's worth it is normally a good idea to separate out your javascript handling code and placing it into a ready event e.g:-

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("input[name='price']").click(function() {
        $('#displayPrice').html($(this).val());
    });
});
```